# bash regex: get value between html tags spanning multiple lines

Tags: regex, grep

I have an HTML file that looks like this:

```
<td class='job-title'>
<h3>
<a href="/postings/46670">Line Cook</a>
</h3>
</td>
```

I am trying to fetch the value of `Line Cook` from the HTML above.
How would I go about doing this using grep and regular expressions?

Comment: You mean you actually want to get the string "Line Cook?"  I think we need more context...

Comment: does it have to use grep? What about sed or awk or any other regex engine?

Comment: What about **HTML PARSER** (oh, thoughtcrime)

Comment: I don't have to use grep, but I tried using sed, but my HTML doc will have multiple job titles. It was my understanding that sed was naturally greedy and would only return the last instance of the td class

Comment: Do you know that the HTML will always look like this? In general regular expressions are not sufficiently powerful to parse HTML. If you're limited to a subset of HTML like this regular expressions may be an option, but you still might be better served by a full-fledged HTML parser.

Comment: Yes. The HTML will always look like this.

Comment: Better use XPath or CSS. `.job-title h3 a`

Comment: @AntonKovalenko : Do you know a single one which work as a single executable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This short grep line should do the job:

```
grep -oP "(?<=>)[^<]*" file
```

However, your HTML codes must be in that format (e.g. `>Line Cook<`) must be on one line otherwise grep will fail.  If the HTML is big you better turn to a parser.

Answer (score 0):

This may or may not be what you want depending what the rest of your file looks like:

```
$ gawk -F'[<>]' -v RS='</td>\n' '{print $(NF-4)}' file
Line Cook
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar challenge. I needed to capture the contents of the last table cell in HTML response using a shell script from Jenkins.

```
<BODY bgcolor=#dddddd>
<TABLE bgcolor=#dddddd border=1>
<TR>
<TD valign="top"><B>aliasName</B></TD>
<TD>jms_aliasName</TD>
</TR>
<TR>
<TD valign="top"><B>messageCount</B></TD>
<TD>0</TD>
</TR>
</TABLE>
</BODY>
```

Using curl to invoke the service to create this page I piped it to the following and put in variable.

```
response=`/usr/bin/curl -s http://$host:$port/invoke/CustomService?aliasName=jms_aliasName | sed -n '/<TD>/,/<\/TD>/H; /<TD>/h; /\/TD/{x;s/<TD>\(.*[^\n]\)\n*<\/TD>/\1/p;}' | tail -n 1`
```

Thanks to others for the sed command which is the magic.

```
| sed -n '/<TD>/,/<\/TD>/H; /<TD>/h; /\/TD/{x;s/<TD>\(.*[^\n]\)\n*<\/TD>/\1/p;}' | tail -n 1
```